# SQLAnywhere: Failure on creation of procedure

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere

I wanted to create a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE __generate_new_VSN(@oldVSN varchar(100)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN '1'
END
```

but getting when running it via isql:

```
Anweisung konnte nicht ausgeführt werden.
Syntaxfehler bei 'RETURNS' in Zeile 2
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3-Status="42000"
Zeile 1, Spalte 1
```

which can be translated to something like

```
Command couldn't be executed
Syntax error at 'RETURNS' on line 2
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3-Status="42000"
Zeile 1, Spalte 1
```

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing the CREATE FUNCTION syntax with that for CREATE PROCEDURE

This should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE __generate_new_VSN(@oldVSN varchar(100), OUT @newVSN  varchar(100)) 
BEGIN
      RETURN '1'
END
```

the full syntax is [here](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbreference/create-procedure-user-defined-statement.html*d5e41257)

Comment: This did the trick -- thanks. Weird is, that similar examples did work.

Comment: If you want a result set you can use a "RESULT" clause - you aren't thinking of that by any chance eg 

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE __generate_new_VSN(@oldVSN varchar(100))
    RESULT (@newVSN  varchar(100))
    BEGIN
          RETURN '1'
    END

Comment: Ahh.... Found the issue at all: Was a funny mixup of procedure and functions .. Just solved it by cleaning up a little. Thanks for the input!